# Calculating several cells into one cell in same table using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7

I'm very new to Python and scripting in ArcGIS.
I need to calculate some cells from one field in table into another one cell in another field in same table.

Here's what i need:

[image]

Here's what i try and it doesnt work.

> > > A = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("S2_merge2", ["Name1"] , 'FID = 0')
> > >          B = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("S2_merge2", ["Name1"] , 'FID = 1')
> > >          C = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("S2_merge2", ["Name1"] , 'FID = 2')
> > >
> > > cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("S2_merge2", ["Name5"] , FID = 0')
> > >
> > > ```
> > > for row in cursor:      
> > >     row[0] = A+B+C   
> > >     cursor.updateRow(row)
> > > ```

Comment: Do you need to calculate field 'Name5' for all rows or only for the first row of your table?

Comment: How would you handle naming the last row in the field "Name5"? A complete example of your intended output would be helpful.

Comment: I need result as shown in picture - only one cell in Name5 should be changed (first row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first copy the column "Name1" in a python list

```
features = [[row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("S2_merge2", ("Name1") )]
```

then use the indices with your search cursor (note that I use a selection to avoid troubles with the last 2 rows, as you did not tell how to manage those)

```
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("S2_merge2", ["Name5"],  'FID < ' + str(int(arcpy.GetCount_management("S2_merge2").getOutput(0))-2) )

i=0
for row in cursor:      
    row[0] = features[i] + features[i+1] + features[i+2]
    cursor.updateRow(row)
    i+=1
```

with a single row :

```
fid_val = 42 #42 is just an example
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("S2_merge2", ["Name5"],  'FID = ' + str(fid_val) )


for row in cursor:      
    row[0] = features[fid_val] + features[fid_val+1] + features[fid_val+2]
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: as I understand - " .getOutput(0))-2) ) " means that ALL-2 row's will be updated - is there any way to Update only one row? (for exemple i dont know quantity of rows in table)

Comment: you can use any query as third argument , so FID = 0 would dot the trick for a single row. Note that if you start from another FID value than 0, you need to initialize i to this FID value. Also note that getcount will give you the quantity of rows, so you don't have to worry about not knowing it